# KalViewController view is Black

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store

i am using Kal Library for Calendar view in my App but it is showing in Black color but when i add same library in another App e.g new SingleViewApp it works fine and show a normal calendar

my code is

```
kal = [[KalViewController alloc] init];
kal.title = @"NativeCal";

kal.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Today" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showAndSelectToday)] autorelease];

kal.delegate = self;
dataSource = [[EventKitDataSource alloc] init];
kal.dataSource = dataSource;

// Setup the navigation stack and display it.
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:kal];



UITabBarController *tabBar  = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
tabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:navController];

self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
self.window.rootViewController = tabBar;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

it gives me this

[image]

Comment: Has it got to do with setting the backgroundColor property? Have you tried changing it?

Comment: Yes i try it out but nothing change

Comment: You probably forgot to include the `Kal.bundle` package in your app's resources - this happened to me the other day.

Comment: @user1278066 which iphone simulator/device you have used for testing?

Comment: Yes Richard J.Ross 111 You are right, kindly write your answer in answer section so that i can choose it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have forgot to include the `Kal.bundle` file, containing all of Kal's resources, in your project's resources. Simply dragging the bundle into your Xcode project should do the trick.